# How to check css's :invalid base class on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I know on blur in css is not a thing but I want that the same thing that happens in this ex.

```css
input:focus:invalid  {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
```

will happen on blur is there a way using a different language like JS or jquery etc to run the check? I know there is a way to check if text is valid using those languages but it does not work with what I do [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eydfhgrn/)

ps
If I wasn't clear: trying to run css class using css+html valid/pattern but on blur

Comment: What does valid/invalid mean here?

Comment: The pattern is "pattern=\d+" so only numbers in other words

Comment: So your question is can you verify the input value is a number and add/remove CSS classes on blur in JavaScript ?

Comment: In a way yes but I tried to verify the text using few different code in JS and jquery and all of them didnt support any other language other than English.
But I know to remove / add classes using  jquery

Comment: Um.... the equivalent to `:blur` in CSS is to override anything you want different on `:focus`. The default state of all elements is the hypothetical `:blur`, so an invalid input that doesn't have focus is `input:invalid`

Comment: @abluejelly so that mean that if I take the :focus it will work on blur?

Comment: @saarsc Yeah, if all you're looking to do is have the `:invalid` style apply when the element lacks focus but the input is marked as `:invalid`...

Comment: If you're wanting to validate the input via regex, slap in a `pattern` attribute. If you're trying to validate it as a special case, you're looking for `onblur` to trigger some JS. Remember to use `eleToClearErrorOn.setCustomValidity("");` and `eleToSetErrorOn.setCustomValidity("Non-Empty Error String");` so `:invalid` works with your JS. EDIT NOTE: deleted and readded since I caught a major typo in the sample JS _after_ the 5-min edit window expired. Heh.

Comment: Just tried to remove the :focus and the code does not update I enter only numbers to the text box(what the user need to do) and the invalid class still run

Comment: Sounds like something is cascading on top of it. Make sure your `input:invalid` rule is the last in the cascade for `input`. Alternatively, provide the actual code (or a good representation thereof) and I won't have to guess why it doesn't work.

Comment: Give me a sec and ill add js fiddle link in the OP